# Azure DevOps pipelines agent do not work behind CNTLM proxy?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My agents are running behind a local CNTLM proxy running on port 3128.
When this task is executed I always get the following error message:

### [error]Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3128

Does this task not support a proxy setup for the agent?

The version of the task is: 1.156.1

Comment: have you seen [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows)?

Comment: Hi @user12484345 Did you config the proxy for your agent following above document? Did it work out? You can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#remove-and-re-configure-an-agent) to re-config your agent.

Comment: Hi,
yes we have done it accordingly. The problem seems to be that in the container (Maven) that is instantiated and used in the build pipeline the proxy is not visible.
Will let you know when the problem is solved and how we solved it.
We are currently working on that.

Comment: Hi @user12484345 Did you work it out? Please do share out how you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the summary of changes to solve it:

Background: One linux VM running 4 agents (as service). CNTLM proxy is running on the VM on port 3128. IP of the VM is 172.17.0.1.

pipelines.yml
resources:
    containers: 
        - container: maven3 
          image: maven:3-jdk-8
          # tmp volume mount can be removed as soon as https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/367290/maven-task-fails-because-maveninfo-cannot-be-publi.html is fixed
          options: -v /local/home/rbadmin_app2/.m2/repository:/home/rbadmin_VSTSContainer/.m2/repository -v /tmp:/tmp -e HTTP_PROXY="http://172.17.0.1:3128" -e HTTPS_PROXY="http://172.17.0.1:3128"

Configuration on Server that is running our 4 agents:
CNTLM:
listen on "docker IP":3128
Docker IP can found by command: ip address
It will be the inet of docker0:

On (host running agents): 172.17.0.1:3128
/etc/sysctl.conf:
Add below setting:
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
Configuration on VSTS:
Set the docker-ip based proxy in file .proxy of the VSTS root directory
Steps (example on host running agents as service):
if not exist create file /.proxy
Content: 172.17.0.1:3128